# Combobox binding does not works in deseriliazation in wpf

Tags: wpf, c#-4.0

I am binding selectedItem property of combobox to some custom object and  i am using serilization.        When application is currently running,then binding works fine. while stopping an application i am seriliazing the object.Now when i starts application ,i am deseriliazing the object and retrieving the values. 
     Now if I sees the comobox binding, it does not show any binding. However, it still shows items in combobox. I  have overridden the Equals method in my class. But still i am not seeing   any binding.
This is my some code:

```
  [Serializable]
public class MyModel : ViewModelBase
{
    private int _id;
    public int Id
    {
        get { return _id; }
        set
        {
            _id = value;
            OnPropertyChanged(() => Id);
        }
    }

    private string _name;
    public string Name
    {
        get { return _name; }
        set
        {
            _name = value;
            OnPropertyChanged(() => Name);
        }
    }

    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        if (obj == null) return false;

        if (this.GetType() != obj.GetType()) return false;

        return this.Id == ((MyModel )obj).Id || this.Name == ((MyModel )obj).Name;

    }


}



  [Serializable]
```

public class MyViewModel : ViewModelBase
{

```
private MyModel _selectedMyModel; 
 [XmlIgnore]
    public MyModel SelectedMyModel 
    {
        get
        {

            return _selectedMyModel ;
        }
        set
        {
            _selectedMyModel  = value;
            this.OnPropertyChanged(() => SelectedYAxisDetail);
        }
    }
```

}

My Xaml is:-

```
 <ComboBox     SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedMyModel , Mode=TwoWay}"   DisplayMemberPath="Name" ItemsSource= "{Binding DataContext.MyModelSource,RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type UserControl}}}"
                       >'
```

Comment: Does this mean, you bind to and serialize the same object? If so, it means you mix your viewmodel and model, which is not so great. Apart from that: Please show some code. XAML, serializing, and properties in viewmodel would be helpful.

Comment: Hello @hSchroedl.I have just uploaded some code snippets please have a look at this and let me know if i am doing anything wrong.

Comment: Okay, I dont get it. Code looks fine. If the combobox shows the right items, what exactly do you mean by "But still i am not seeing any binding"?

Comment: I mean combobox is showing all the items populated in it but it is not showing  selected item in combobbox.I mean SelectedItem of combobox is not working.